# css class calling using comma and dot

Tags: css, class, background

I've used the following line to change a background image size
`.entry-header.background-image`
but it didn't work

What worked was:
`.entry-header,background-image`

can somebody explain?

Comment: Well, not without seeing your HTML we can't. Maybe you could make a working example?

Comment: `.entry-header.background-image` specifies that both classes live on the same element. The other definition is invalid css. The `.entry-header` would match but the `background-image` doesn't have an identifier defined. Without any code it's tricky to determine exactly what your issue is

Answer (score 3):

Ideally some code would help but in general consider:

- `.entry-header` seems a class if it uses dot - `.class {background-image: url("image.jpg");}`
- `Background-image` is a property - eg. `div {background-image:
  url("image.jpg");}`.
- Comma is used to separate classes, ids or elements - `div, p, a {property: value;}` or `.class1, .class2, #id {property: value;}`
- When using `.class.class2 {property: value;}` means both classes are set to the same element.